# Add multiple row and column fields to a PivotTable

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table

**What I'm trying to do**: Add multiple row and column fields to the pivot table.

**My code**: I have the row and column fields in a list and in an array object. I've tried to assign the fields from both and they both give me an error.

**Method 1**: List

//PTRowFields is a list where the row fields are stored

```
foreach (var item in PTRowFields)
{
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField Rfield = PT.PivotFields(item);
     Rfield.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
}
```

**Method 2**: Array

//PTrowfields is an array where the row fields are stored

```
int num = PTrowfields.Count();
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField rowfield = PT.PivotFields(PTrowfields[i]);
     rowfield.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
     rowfield.Position = i + 1;
}
```

**Error I receive**:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occured in mscorlip.dl

Additional information: PivotFields method of PivotTable class failed

Found a thread on a similar topic in [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/97821314-933d-4b5c-9548-196d82612a91/pivot-table-excel-c-adding-multiple-rowfield) but that doesn't seem to work for me.